# Freshly cloned repo shows many files in changed stated in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, when a Repo is cloned it shows many files as changes.

These are mainly:

.suo

.sqlite

.ide

.cache (these are from obj, debug, and release folders)

These are included in .gitignore file but still show in the Changes panel.

The problem is on Cloning, Visual Studio shows the code in the 'master' branch. It will not allow switching to any other, (read)develop, branch because of the change tracked.

The workaround for now is to undo all the changes right after cloning, switch to the required branch and get on with the days work.

Can anyone please guide on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `.gitignore` hasn't been checked in in the original repo.

Check out

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore